# How to create multiple in-line forms for a list property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a view where a user can update (create/edit) multiple Journal Entries (one for each journal) at the same time.

ViewModel:

```
public class CompanyRecoMonthViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public string RecoMonth { get; set; }
}
```

Company has a list of Journals:

```
public virtual IList<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
```

Every journal has a list of JournalEntries

```
public  IList<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; }
```

In each month Journal will have one (or none) JournalEntry .

From the controller I'm loading the Journals into the view.

Now the code in the view. I'm trying to put the inline forms into a table view.
My problem is that upon submitting the form none of the values are captured.

Probably not using the @Html.BeginForm properly. Seems that form doesn't know which object it is meant to edit.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Person Responsible
        </th>
        <th>
            Journal Number
        </th>
        <th>
            SomeID
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Upload Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount<
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Company.Journals)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JournalNumber)
            </td>

            <!-- this is where we start inline form for Journal Entry-->
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "JournalEntries",  FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <form class="form-inline">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.JournalID)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.JournalEntries[0].SomeID, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "8" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.JournalEntries[0].Status, Model.JournalStatuses.Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.JournalEntries[0].DatePosted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.JournalEntries[0].JournalType, Model.JournalTypes.Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.JournalEntries[0].AmountPosted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </form>
            }

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Pls post your controller POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to achieve that using multiple partial views with inline-forms for one entity per partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Add **virtual** keyword to JournalEntries property in your Journal class to navigate to the JournalEntry class.

```
public virtual IList<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; }
```